# Trying to set up multiple OS partitions, that both point to the same home partition, inside LUKS container

Tags: encryption, home-directory, luks

Encryptfs has been removed from 18.04, in favour of full disk encryption (LUKS). See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1756613) for confirmation. This means that my current set up of having an encrypted home directory on a different partition is harder to replicate.

Basically, I like to have two OS partitions (sdb5 and sdb6), that both have their encrypted /home directories on a different partition (sdb8), because it makes it easier to distro-hop.

How can I set this up, all within an encrypted LUKS container, when installing ubuntu from a livecd?

I want to replicate this set up within a LUKS container: [image: 2]]

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but I think you might want to use different usernames on each. I also want to know which distros and version you are trying to install.  Also mounting all your partitions and including the output of  lsblk might be helpful. I can see that you have this on /dev/sdb meaning it might see at least two disks.  I personally don't know how to create a luks container that is not a whole disk in the ubiquity installer itself.

Comment: Hi. I am fine to use different usernames on each, as long as both are on the same partition (sdb8). I would like to have Ubuntu and Solus. I am fine to have the LUKS container take up the whole disk as well.